# Using ValueInjecter, can I inject into private properties?

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

Is there any Injection in ValueInjecter that injects into private properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build one, you can inherit the **IValueInjection**, use reflection and go through all the properties private or public, or both, however you need, and set the values from one object to another